# Unipotent group action on a projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

It is known that the orbits of a unipotent algebraic group in an affine variety are closed copies of the affine space.

My question is about algebraic unipotent group orbits in the projective variety. Are they also closed or (and) copies of an affine space?